# Could we replace multiple WCF calls by a single WCF call?

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, httpcontext

I am currently working with mvc4 application that reads data from a set of wcf services. Currently when a user hits a page number, if wcf requests are triggered to get data for different parts of the page. I want to improve its performance.

My idea is, when a user lands on a page a single wcf call is made which retrieves all the necessary data that the multiple calls previously did and put the data from it in to the users request httpcontext.

Is this improving performance than the approach single but larger wcf call over named pipes or multiple smaller calls under named pipes? Are there any performance implications of putting a large set of data in to the httpcontext?

Comment: If you made the multiple calls in an asychronous fashion, then you could have higher throughput.

Comment: The multiple calls are not made but at different times in pages lifecycle so therefore not possible to do the above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to solve one problem by producing even more problems. 
If you query all the data at a time and store in httpcontext it will speed up performance for opening new pages but it will take considerably longer to open the page for the first time. Also you may easily run out of memory especially if you have many users at a time if storing data in httpcontext per a user.

I think first you need to localize the problem and find the root cause of poor performance. It may be a query or it may be some database locks.
in any case caching is a good idea, but don't use httpcontext for it. Use ASP.NET cahe or some distributed cache like App Fabric. These tools will provide you with a lot of built-in features and it will be easier for you to then scale your application.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback - I have the data cached and was considering reading it in to user context for each request so it could be accessed easily. Yes the site will be accessed by large numbers. Based on what you said holding items in context has memory implications? Also, could you explain the following as I dont understand " If you query all the data at a time and store in httpcontext it will speed up performance for opening new pages but it will take considerably longer to open the page for the first time.".

Comment: As far as I understood you have a web page with some data which is split by pages. When a user hits a page number link you make a WCF service call to get data for a particular page. So when a user lands on your web page you only get data for page number one. Right? If yes, then if you get all data when a user opens your web page for the first time it will take much longer than just getting first page of data.